# MainActivity file in Android

Tags: java, android

Building rn app into library & in Android, there is `MainActivity.Java` file

I went through tutorial point where they have give this definition.

> is contains the .java source files for your project. By default, it includes an MainActivity.java source file having an activity class that runs when your app is launched using the app icon.

From this definition, does it mean that there can be only one MainActivity.java file in an app? and if someone was to create an sdk in Android, it can't have MainActivity.java file? I saw other RN open source repo/library and none of them have MainActivity.java

Comment: `MainActivity` is just the typical name of the default activity (class) of an android application.

Answer (score 0):

You are not required to have a MainActivity.java it can be named anything. The most important thing is that you declare it in your AndroidManifest.xml file all Activities need to be declared there.

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.company.project.YourActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```